# Multiple videos embedded, the first video is playing everywhere theres a video

Tags: html, css, image, video

I have a blog style page with paragraphs and after every paragraph theres a photo and a video. Wherever there is a video, the first video is playing

I have this layout multiple times in a row. For example the first time is picture1 and video1 and the second time is picture2 and video2.
Whats being played is picture1 and video1, then picture2 and video1 the whole way down. Why is this happening ?

HTML:

```
<div class="entry">
   <p>Para</p>
</div>

<div class="image">
   <img src="image.jpg">
</div>
<div class="image">
   <video><source src="image=.MP4">   </video>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.entry p{
    font-family: "Reenie Beanie";
    font-size: 33px;
    margin-left: 35px;
    margin-right: 60px;
    font-weight: lighter;

}
.image img{
    width: 400px;
    height: 550px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 70px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 70px;
    box-shadow: 6px 15px 10px 6px;
    position: relative;
}
.image video{
    width: 400px;
    height: 550px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 70px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 70px;
    box-shadow: 6px 15px 10px 6px;
    position: relative;
 }
```

Comment: Is there any code involved? It seems just fine, and you only have one video in the HTML you present.